# System time and Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am constructing a normal X/Y data plot using column data from a .txt data file. The graph plots well (see general code below).

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to extract and use a System time in conjunction with the logged data in the .txt file?

This is in order to produce an X/Y plot with Y being the data from column [x]  from the .txt file and the x-axis being an extracted system time point ??

The system time is not part of the log file.

The data string contained within the text file looks like this and is `;` delimited: `221.5;65.9;-22.9;0;22.1`

Code to generate the plot:

```
set multiplot layout 5,1
set title "Plot 1"
unset key
plot "data.txt" using 1 with linespoints ls 1
set title "Plot 2"
unset key
plot "data.txt" using 2 with linespoints ls 2
......
unset multiplot
```

In other words, for each data .txt file column point I would like to attach a system time giving as `"Plot 1" {sys.time[x],221.5}` and for `"Plot 2" {sys.time[x],65.9}`.

The next row of file data points delimited by `;` will have another system time attached to each of them.

Thanks

Comment: check `help time`. What date or time would you like to place in front of your data lines? e.g. line1: <current system time>, line 2: <current system time + 1 sec> ... or minutes or hours? Could you please give an example of your actual data lines and the lines with the desired x-values?

Comment: Hi... thanks for the reply.... the actual data (from file) looks like this 221.5;65.9;-22.9;0;22.1 it is semi-colon delimited. I am currently plotting each value separately using 'plot 'z1.txt' using 1 with linespoints ls 1' ... I am trying to perhaps put the date (as day and month) and hour of the day as the x-value with each data point. So in the above example y=221, x = 12/01,13.... the x values are the system time and are not contained within the data file

Comment: Sorry the above is in error .... the required data pair would look like this ... y= 221, x = day,hour,minute,second for example .... thanks

Comment: your data is all in one single line separated by `;`? If the first value `221` gets the current system time, which date/time should the second value `65.9` get? +1 second,or +1 minute, +1 day...?

Comment: I have 5 graphs in a multiplot which are plotted using a) 221, b)65, c)-22, d)0 , e) 22.1 ..at the moment I am plotting these 5 graphs at the same time .... the idea would be to have an x,y co-ord (on each graph within the multiplot) {221 (y), time (x)} .. with time being second then +x seconds etc .... incrementally providing each data string with a time point .,....

Comment: {221, time(x) } , {65,time(x)} , {22,time(x)} then at the next system time point {221,time(x2)}, {65,time(x2)}, {22, time (x2)}   etc ..

Comment: You're plotting 5 datapoints in 5 multiplots? I'm still confused. Could you please edit your question by adding the full gnuplot code you're using, a few lines of data (or is it just these 5 points???) and if possible add an image of the plot output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still a bit guessing, but your image made it a bit more clear.
Maybe we can use this for further tweaking.

Some random data: `data.txt`

```
0.713;0.725;0.579;0.485;0.271
0.861;0.882;0.128;0.772;0.475
0.524;0.076;0.420;0.583;0.068
0.429;0.114;0.907;0.679;0.842
0.684;0.077;0.752;0.165;0.062
0.916;0.865;0.368;0.380;0.843
0.291;0.460;0.272;0.279;0.632
0.908;0.832;0.556;0.259;0.744
0.763;0.735;0.624;0.277;0.520
0.735;0.690;0.145;0.148;0.734
0.041;0.398;0.353;0.764;0.065
0.765;0.049;0.603;0.215;0.636
0.613;0.271;0.770;0.030;0.449
0.512;0.583;0.956;0.994;0.832
0.222;0.061;0.471;0.085;0.880
0.259;0.071;0.065;0.391;0.043
0.077;0.356;0.377;0.590;0.562
0.706;0.343;0.312;0.993;0.659
0.826;0.103;0.908;0.135;0.048
0.393;0.012;0.192;0.017;0.233
```

The code:

```
### adding time data afterwards
reset session

FILE = "data.txt"

set datafile separator ";"

set xdata time
set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
set format x "%d.%m."
TimeIntervalInSeconds = 3600*24 
StartTime = "01.01.2019 12:00"

set ytics 0.5
set multiplot layout 5,1

do for [i=1:5] {
    set title sprintf("Plot %d",i)
    plot FILE using (StartTime+$0*TimeIntervalInSeconds):i w lp lt i notitle
}

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That looks very good ! ... I will give it test and get back to you shortly